# WPF contents of cell of DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, cell, datagridtemplatecolumn

In WPF I have the reference to a DataGridCell and would like to get its contents. I used to have that cell in a DataGridTextColumn and could get at the content like this:

```
var text = cell.Content as TextBlock;
```

But this is not longer working since the cell is in a DataGridTemplateColumn, although I did specify TextBlock as the DataTemplate for that column. Is there still a way to get at it?

EDIT to clarify the problem. The following code is working as intended:

```
<!-- XAML -->
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Autor" Width="*"  Binding="{Binding Author}" />

//C#
var block = _selectedCell.Content as TextBlock;
var text = block.Text; //text contains the string that is also displayed by the grid in that call
```

If I however use a TemplateColumn the code will not work because block will be null.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Autor" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="txtAutor" Text="{Binding Author}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Is there a way to still get at the cells contents (a string in my case)?

Comment: I found a usable solution in this other [question][1] here on stackoverflow. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029324/grabbing-reference-to-element-inside-datagridtemplatecolumn

Comment: Much overcomplicated in this case. You can find your string in `(_selectedCell.DataContext as *cast to parent of Author*).Author`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give your `TextBlock` inside the `DataTemplate` a name, and then use the `Text` property to get the data.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Name="txtData" Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>

var text = txtData.Text as string;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this tomorrow. But it is not immediately obvious to me how I come from the cell to txtData in your example.

Comment: `txtData` is just an arbitrary name I assigned to the TextBlock. You could call it `cell` if you want.

Comment: I understood that. What I mean is: I have the reference to a DataGridCell. How can I use your method to access its contents?

Comment: Can you post some more of your xaml in the OP (or a sample that would accomplish the same thing you are trying to do)? Is the value of `text` null?