# Grabbing reference to element inside DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, datagridtemplatecolumn

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now and can't seem to get any answers on it. I've mocked up a simple XAML file to demonstrate the problem (I'm not providing my real XAML file since it has more in it than needed for this question).

Here is my question: given the following XAML file how can I get a reference in my codebehind to the selectHeight ComboBox that resides in the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate DataTemplate? I need the reference so that I can change a property of the ComboBox based on a selection in the selectAge ComboBox.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="grdPeople"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                    AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" 
                    CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsEnabled="True"
                    MaxHeight="400" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Name Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyName" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False"  CanUserSort="False" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--Age Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyAge">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Age}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="selectAge" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AgeOpts}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Age}"></Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>    
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--Height Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyHeight">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Height}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="selectHeight" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HeightOpts}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Height}"></Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I realize that what I'm trying to do may not be exactly "best practice" but I'm trying to work with what I've been given in legacy code.

I found this MSDN page relating to what I want to do but I can't figure out how to translate the example into my scenario: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a library script I like using to navigate WPF's visual tree and find controls.

You use it like this: `ComboBox cbx = FindChild<ComboBox>(grdPeople, "selectHeight");`

It will return `null` if it can't find any `ComboBox` that is named `"selectHeight"` so be sure to check if `cbx == null` before using it.

```
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;

    T foundChild = null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundChild;
}

public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent is valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;

    T foundChild = null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child);

            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundChild;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I gave this a shot but it was not able to find the control in my example. The MSDN post I linked to mentioned getting the ContentPresenter of the ListBox Item so that you could obtain the DataTemplate that is set on it and then call the FindName method on that DataTemplate. Your method doesn't seem to take into account DataTemplates but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Tom When are you trying to find the ComboBox? Is it visible on the screen when you do?

Comment: No it isn't since its only visible when the cell is in editable mode. If it makes it easier you can download my zipped up solution here: http://dropdo.com/7in/WpfTest. It's in VB.Net. I translated your method into VB. I'm trying to get the reference to the selectHeight ComboBox in the selectAge_SelectionChanged event handler in MainWindow.xaml.vb

Comment: WPF unloads controls that are not visible, so if the ComboBox is not on the screen than it doesn't exist in the visual tree. The ComboBox looks like it's bound to the `Height` property though, so why don't you just use that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using the Height property? I'm trying to set the selectHeight ComboBox as either enabled or disabled based on a the selected value in the selectAge ComboBox. For example if someone picks an age of 30 I want to make the selectHeight ComboBox unavailable.

Comment: From your XAML code, it looks like you have a class containing properties for `Name`, `Age`, and `Height`. You can either use the code-behind to say something like `if (((Person)heightComboBox.DataContext).Age > 30) heightComboBox.IsEnabled = false;`, or you can do it in the XAML using a `DataTrigger` and `Converter` (recommended)

Comment: The whole point is that I'm not able to get a reference to the selectHeight ComboBox in the code behind. So what you're suggesting won't work because it requires a reference to the selectHeight ComboBox.

Comment: Add the code in the above comment to the `Loaded` event of your selectHeight ComboBox. The ComboBox will be the `sender` object so you'll have to cast it `var heightComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I was thinking about it in the context of the selectAge_SelectionChanged event handler in which a ref to the selectHeight ComboBox was not available. This works for me.