# ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn is not resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

### Introduction to the problem

I have a `DataGrid` that has a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, the template of which contains a `ComboBox` control. My problem is that when the displayed member of the selected item is too long to fit into the width of the `ComboBox`, then the width of the `ComboBox` does not expand to accommodate the width of the displayed memeber, as it does if the same `ComboBox` is not in the `DataGrid`.

### Working Example

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <StackPanel>
      <DataGrid Height="150"
                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                ColumnWidth="SizeToCells"
                HeadersVisibility="Column"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                RowHeaderWidth="0"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entities, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntity}"
                SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                SelectionMode="Single">
         <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBox_Template">
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBox_Template">
               <ComboBox Margin="2,2,2,2"
                         Width="Auto"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AvailableActions,
                                               Mode=OneTime,
                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                         SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Action, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         SelectedValuePath="Key"
                         DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                         IsEditable="False"
                         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGrid.Resources>
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                    CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False"
                                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource TextBox_Template}"
                                    Header="Text Field"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto"
                                    CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False"
                                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBox_Template}"
                                    Header="Action"/>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
      <Separator Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Button Content="Add Row" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                 Command="{Binding AddRowCommand}"/>
         <Button Content="Remove Row" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                 Command="{Binding RemoveRowCommand}"/>
      </StackPanel>
      <Separator Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
      <ComboBox Width="Auto"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableActions}"
                SelectedValuePath="Key"
                DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                IsEditable="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public static Dictionary<ActionType, string> AvailableActions { get; set; }

      public EntityClass SelectedEntity { get; set; }

      public ObservableCollection<EntityClass> Entities { get; set; }

      public AddRowCommandClass AddRowCommand { get; set; }

      public RemoveRowCommandClass RemoveRowCommand { get; set; }

      static MainWindow()
      {
         AvailableActions = new Dictionary<ActionType, string>()
         {
            {ActionType.Accept,   "Accept the text"},
            {ActionType.Reject,   "Reject the text"},
            {ActionType.Refer,    "Refer the text"},
            {ActionType.Postpone, "Postpone the text"},
         };
      }

      public MainWindow()
      {
         Entities = new ObservableCollection<EntityClass>()
         {
            new EntityClass() { Text = "First Example Text",  Action = ActionType.Accept},
            new EntityClass() { Text = "Second Example Text", Action = ActionType.Reject},
            new EntityClass() { Text = "Third Example Text",  Action = ActionType.Refer},
         };
         AddRowCommand = new AddRowCommandClass(this);
         RemoveRowCommand = new RemoveRowCommandClass(this);

         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public enum ActionType
      {
         Accept,
         Reject,
         Refer,
         Postpone,
      }

      public class EntityClass
      {
         public string Text { get; set; }
         public ActionType Action { get; set; }
      }

      public class AddRowCommandClass : ICommand
      {
         public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
         private MainWindow _window;

         public AddRowCommandClass(MainWindow window)
         {
            _window = window;
         }

         public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
         {
            return true;
         }

         public void Execute(object parameter)
         {
            _window.Entities.Add(new EntityClass() { Text = "Hello World!", Action = ActionType.Postpone });
         }
      }

      public class RemoveRowCommandClass : ICommand
      {
         public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
         private MainWindow _window;

         public RemoveRowCommandClass(MainWindow window)
         {
            _window = window;
         }

         public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
         {
            return _window.SelectedEntity != null;
         }

         public void Execute(object parameter)
         {
            _window.Entities.Remove(_window.SelectedEntity);
            _window.SelectedEntity = null;
            _window.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(_window, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedEntity"));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Steps to reproduce

- First observe that the `ComboBox` at the bottom of the page changes size as the size of it's selected value changes.
- Next add a new row to the `DataGrid` or edit the `ComboBox` in one of the already present rows to select the `"Postpone the text"` option; notice how the `ComboBox` doesn't change size to fit the larger text, leading to the text being clipped.
- Finally resize the window to a larger size with one of the rows having selected `"Postpone the text"`, and notice how the `ComboBox` now increases in width to accommodate the longer text without clipping.

### Conclusion/Question

My question is how can I force the `ComboBox` controls to automatically accommodate the width of their selected item, and increase the width of the grid row if necessary to do so. I want it such that the selected text will never be clipped, even if this means modifying the width of particular columns in the `DataGrid` to accommodate.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the DataGridTemplateColumn directly instead of creating a DataTemplate in the Resources? I had some problems with this before.

Comment: @lightlike I'm afraid I don't follow what you mean, I thought the idea of a `DataGridTemplateColumn` was to apply a `DataTemplate` to a cell. I don't know how you would directly add a `ComboBox` to a column.

Comment: Try looking at [WPF contents of cell of DataGridTemplateColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840344/wpf-contents-of-cell-of-datagridtemplatecolumn). You have more possibilities if you do it like that. Will also add an answer for your Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is reproducable with a lot simpler datagrid: just place a star-sized column in front of another column that is not star-sized. The Layout process will not try to shrink the columns to the left in order to give columns to the right more space as long as the grid size as a whole stays the same.

The following solution is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651287/5265292

Establish some event that indicates a possibly necessary column resize, then remove the star size column widths, update the layout, restore the column widths. In my example, I used the `SelectionChanged` event and need to dispatch the layout update for it to work:

```
void dg1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is ComboBox)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                dg1.Columns[0].Width = new DataGridLength();
                dg1.UpdateLayout();
                dg1.Columns[0].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
            }));
    }
}
```

My sample XAML with items sources in code behind:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ComboBoxItemsSource" Source="{Binding ComboItems}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid
        x:Name="dg1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        SelectionChanged="dg1_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="*"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                Header="B"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComboBoxItemsSource}}"
                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

For sake of completeness, the initialization and viewmodels:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid1.DataContext = vm = new MyViewModel()
    {
        DataItems =
        {
            new ItemVM(),
        },
        ComboItems =
        {
            "A",
            "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        }
    };
}


public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemVM> _DataItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemVM>();
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> DataItems
    {
        get { return _DataItems; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _ComboItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItems
    {
        get { return _ComboItems; }
    }
}


public class ItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set { _Text = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: That appears to be the ticket. I implemented this in my example program and the sizing now appears to be correctly handled. Thank you very much :D

Comment: I've marked this question as answered, but I'll leave the bounty until the end of the day, just on the off chance someone proposes an alternative solution that I find more preferable, but I think this is unlikely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your provided solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the width of the second column from "auto" to "*", just like you did in the first column. And then setting a MaxWidth so the combobox wont get to big when sizing.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" MaxWidth="200"
                                CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False"
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBox_Template}"
                                Header="Action"/>
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, unfortunately this will raise two issues that I would like to avoid: First I don't know how long the strings are (the actual strings may be under translation so have indeterminate length) which means that any max width may be too small; Second I'm not sure that `*` sizing is the correct sizing for this problem as this will give too much space to the `ComboBox`, taking it away from other columns, resulting in wasted space.

Comment: Hmm oke tricky, then i would suggest finding a way to change the width of combobox based on width of its widest element. Have a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034505/how-can-i-make-a-wpf-combo-box-have-the-width-of-its-widest-element-in-xaml

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the DataTemplate directly to the 'DataGridTemplateColumn'.

I would do something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto"
                        CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False"
                        Header="Action">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ComboBox Margin="2 2 2 2"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AvailableActions,
                                           Mode=OneTime,
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Action, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     SelectedValuePath="Key"
                     DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                     IsEditable="False"
                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, the essential part is you need a star-sized column in front of the column that is required to resize in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @grek40 I had a `*`-Column before an `Auto`-Column before and never ran into this problem, but I wouldn't say that this is the definite answer, it just worked for me.

Comment: Tested, and unfortunately this does not solve my problem on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried HorizontalAlignment and/or HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch on the combobox?

Comment: Tested, and unfortunately this does not solve my problem.